# Print a string in mips assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

How to print a string that was previously read from a user in mips assembly?

That is what I'm trying:

```
.text
main:

li $v0, 8 #user input
syscall

li $a0, $v0 #is this correct to print the string??
syscall
```

Comment: syscall 8 requires: `$a0 = address of input buffer` and  `$a1 = maximum number of characters to read` which you do not have provided, then you use `syscall 4` to print the string by providing to `$a0` the address of the input buffer used in `syscall 8`...

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. Before you call syscall 8 (read string) you need to set `$a0` to the address of the buffer where the string should be stored, and `$a1` to the size of the buffer.

When you want to print the string you need to set `$v0` to 4 (syscall 4 == print string), and `$a0` to the address of the string.

Information about the syscalls available in SPIM [can be found online](https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/lab/secondyear/spim/node8.html).

Comment: My answer explains what you need to do. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: just don't know which command to put first and what to assign to $a0.